# When storing password hashes should they be kept in a file or database?

Tags: php, database, security, blowfish

In a website that requires users to log on where are their password hashes stored? I'm thinking they could be stored in a text file or database. Also I plan on using Blowfish to produce the hash that will be saved. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Yes, just please -- never use md5!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored in a database, this way they are far more accessible and easy to work with.